# How can I parse output from GPS using Arduino Uno?

Tags: parsing, arduino, gps, output

I have connected an Arduino Uno and GPS module and when I open the serial monitor it's showing all the data. But I need to **parse data** (longitude, latitude, time, speed, etc.) **from the output of the GPS using Arduino Uno**. I tried many codes from many sites but didn't obtain the result. Please anyone specify the full steps to be followed and provide the full codes. I have seen many specifying the same problem.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TinyGPS++](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus) library. It's easy to use and have great example code. It uses SoftwareSerial so read the comment in the top of the example code to connect your GPS correctly. You also might have to change the GPSbaud to 9600 if you are using a NEO GPS module.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote codes as per the link given by XerXeX .It worked and obtained the result.Here's what i did

1. Download the TinyGPS++ from https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/releases (unzip the file and paste it to Arduino “libraries” folder,You should rename the folder “TinyGPSPlus” and restart Arduino IDE.)
2. codes will be now available in examples for parsing data.

any doubts you can refer http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/